# Notice: Undefined index in session

Tags: php

I having this error Notice: Undefined index: uid_fb

please help

```
<?php 
include "common.php";
if($_SESSION['uid_fb']!='' && $_SESSION['login_fb']=='true')
{
// header("Location:home.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   include "common.php";
   if (!empty($_SESSION['uid_fb']) &&
        isset($_SESSION['login_fb']) &&
        $_SESSION['login_fb']=='true')
   {
      // ...
   }
```

Use [`isset`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine if a variable has a value.  Use [`empty`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.empty.php) to determine if a variable is not set, or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Add `isset`:

```
<?php 
include "common.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['uid_fb']) && $_SESSION['uid_fb']!='' && $_SESSION['login_fb']=='true')
{
// header("Location:home.php"); 
}
```